# Datatype for accessing data in multidimensional arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows:

```
@spaces = []
def make_board
  7.times do |x|
    x += 1
    6.times do |y|
      y += 1
      @spaces << [x," "]
    end
  end
end
```

...and a series of desired combinations:

```
def winners 
    #V row 1 
    [ [[0][1], [1][1], [2][1], [3][1]], 
    [[1][1], [2][1], [3][1], [4][1]], 
    [[2][1], [3][1], [4][1], [5][1]],
    #V row 2
    [[6][1], [7][1], [8][1], [9][1]],
    [[7][1], [8][1], [9][1], [10][1]],
    [[8][1], [9][1], [10][1], [11][1]],
    #V row 3
    [[12][1], [13][1], [14][1], [15][1]],
    [[13][1], [14][1], [15][1], [16][1]],
    [[14][1], [15][1], [16][1], [17][1]] ]
end
```

Throughout the rest of the program, the " " in the @spaces array can be changed to either "X" or "O". I'm trying to write a method that detects when any of the combinations are not " " and all have the same value.

```
def @win? = false
def success
  winners.each do |x|
    fours = [ @spaces[x[0]], @spaces[x[1]], @spaces[x[2]], @spaces[x[3]] ]
    if fours.each{|x| x[1] != " "}
      if @spaces[x[0]] == @spaces[x[1]] && @spaces[x[1]] == @spaces[x[2]] && @spaces[x[2]] == @spaces[x[3]]
        @win = true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It doesn't like the data type being passed from #winners array the #success method to search the @spaces array. It reads it as nil and wants an integer, but adding .to_i results in everything coming across as 0. Varying and assorted combinations of adding brackets, " ", and whatever else in response to the error messages has just resulted in more nil and 0.  **What data type is necessary to make the method work?** Alternatively, in the likely case I'm going about it in a particularly stupid manner and just don't realize it yet **Could anyone suggest an alternative means of accomplishing the same goal?**

The 6X7 grid is a "connect four" board. Each subarray[0] in the @sample array is the column, and is used in other parts of the program. Each subarray[1] is the "X", "O", or " " (unused). The program is a game of "connect four" for learning purposes

Comment: `@spaces` is an array of 42 elements of the form `[i,s]`, where `i` is a number between `1` and `7` (inclusive) and `s` is initially `" "`, but may be changed to `"X"` or `"O"`. What is the meaning of the `j`th element of `@spaces`?

Comment: Where are you getting the `j`th element?

Comment: `j` references the element of `@spaces` at position (or index or offset) `j`, where `j` is an arbitrary number between `0` and `41`.  Say, for example, `j=21`.

Comment: Ah. In those terms, each element `j` represents a space on a 6X7 grid. `j[0]` is the column and is used in other parts of the program. `j[1]` is the "X", "O", or " " (unused). The program is a game of "connect four" for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your definition of `winners` is a little off. In particular

```
[0][1] # => nil
```

Because you're essentially creating an array `[0]` then immediately asking for element in position 1, which is nil (the array only has an element in position 0). Since all the arrays are single element, winners looks like this

```
[ [nil, nil, nil, nil], 
[nil, nil, nil, nil], 
[nil, nil, nil, nil],
# etc
```

I *think* what you want is this

```
[ [0, 1, 2, 3], 
[1, 2, 3, 4], 
[2, 3, 4, 5],
```

That will make this line

```
fours = [ @spaces[x[0]], @spaces[x[1]], @spaces[x[2]], @spaces[x[3]] ]
```

So, for the first array in `winners`

```
fours = [ @spaces[0], @spaces[1], @spaces[2], @spaces[3] ]
```

Which may look like

```
# the first 6 elements of spaces have x = 1, so all 1's here
fours = [ [1, " "], [1, " "], [1, " "], [1, " "] ]
```

...depending on the state of the game. After that, your code gets a little off. It looks like you're trying to check that all four of those `fours` has the same value in the space AND that value isn't blank. Using the structure you have:

```
if fours.all? { |space| space[1] != " " }
  if fours[0][1] == fours[1][1] &&
       fours[1][1] == fours[2][1] &&
       fours[2][1] == fours[3][1]
    @win = true
  end
end
```

That should work, or at least be close, if I'm understanding your structure correctly.

ALL of that being said, I would change the structure here pretty significantly, if you can. To begin, I'd represent the board as an array of arrays, where you can access any location with just x, y coordinates, like so

```
board = 7.times.map { Array.new(6, " ") }
board[0][0] # => " "
```

You can either use 0- or 1- based coordinates, but if you're using 1 you'll have to subtract 1 every time you access the array.

Filling a square is easy

```
board[x][y] = "O"
```

You can enumerate all your winners as coordinate pairs (note the use of a constant, since this never changes):

```
WINNERS = [
  [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0]], # horizontal win
  [[0,0], [1,1], [2,2], [3,3]], # diagonal win
  # etc
]
```

And then check through those

```
WINNERS.each do |win_row|
  if win_row.all? { |x, y| board[x][y] == "X" } || win_row.all? { |x, y| board[x][y] == "O" }
    @win = true
    break
  end
end
```

You could algorithmically determine the winners as well, if you don't want to construct and store the winners array.

Comment: Nailed it! That's the ticket... Now I realize have other issues, but that part makes sense and functions now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first problem...
`[0]` is an array with only one element.
`[0][1]` is saying "get the second element of the array" (index 1) but there is no second element, so that returns nil.

I think instead of `[0][1]` you really wanted to do just `0`, etc.

```
def winners 

    #V row 1 
    [ 
      [0, 1, 2, 3], 
      [1, 2, 3, 4], 
      [2, 3, 4, 5],
    #V row 2
      [6, 7, 8, 9],
      [7, 8, 9, 10],
      [8, 9, 10, 11],
    #V row 3
      [12, 13, 14, 15],
      [13, 14, 15, 16],
      [14, 15, 16, 17]
    ]
end
```

Next problem is this line...

```
if fours.each{|x| x[1] != " "}
```

... doesn't do what you think it does.  An `each` block returns the iterated array, not `true` or `false`.  What you want is...

```
if fours.select{|x| x[1] == " "}.empty?
```

Which will return `true` if there are no cells with " " in the second element.